# Unable to set the value to the first input field using id of the field - in vue

Tags: vue.js

I have an input field and a button (when clicked on displays a dropdown with few items) when selecting the items it has to be shown on the first input field. Similarly when clicking on the 2nd button where the dropdown is shown the selected value is shown in the 2nd input field. This entire runs in a for loop , which is where I am facing the problem.

```html
<tr v-for="items in itemList">
  <td valign="top">&nbsp;{{items}}&nbsp;</td>
  <td align="left" nowrap>
  <input v-model="itemCode" type="text" :id="'item_code_'+items" 
     @input="handleInput" 
     size="20" maxlength="27"
     autocomplete="off">
   <br/>
   </td>
   <td align="left" nowrap>
     <a id="myDropdown" class="dropdown" style="text-decoration:none;font- 
       size:10pt; padding-left: 10px;padding-right: 10px;"
       @click="loadFavs()"
       href="javascript:void(0)" title="Click to choose an item from your 
       favorites">
     <img hspace="3" alt="Favorites" src="/images/icons/LoadFav.png" 
         height="16" width="16"
         onmousemove="this.style.cursor='pointer'" 
         :id="'bd_fav_image_' + items" title="Click to choose an item from 
         your favorites">
       <select class="dropdown-content" v-if="showFav" name="BOMList" 
         :id="'bd_list_'+items" style="font-size:10pt;width: 100%" v- 
         model="selected" @change="selectingFav(items)">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option  v-for="(fav,index) in favList" :id="index" v- 
             bind:value="fav"  :key="fav" v-bind:index="index">{{fav}} 
             {{index}}</option>
       </select>
      </a>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" nowrap >
        <input type="Text"
           :id="'bd_qty_ '+ index"
           value="" size="2"
           inputmode="numeric"
           maxlength="">
         </td>
       </tr>
```

favList--> this list holds a list of items , For eg:- A,B,C,D
When I select A it has to be shown in the input field.

```js
 selectingFav: function(value) {
            console.log("Inside the selectingFav..." + this.selected + "value is ." +value);
            setTheValue(value);

            
        }
function setTheValue(val){
    console.log("Inside the setThevlaue");
    if (val === 1 ){
        console.log("inside the if");
        $j('#item_code_1').val(this.selected);
        console.log("inside the if witht the value  " + $j('#item_code_1').val());
    }
```

Tried setting the value based on the id of the input field but nothing is showing up.
If I set the v-model to the input field then all the 3 fields will be showing up the same value.

Can someone please let me know what is the issue. Hope these details are sufficient.

Comment: what's $j and why don't you use v-model on input?

Comment: i did try using v-model but when I set the value to the v-model then all the 3 input fields will be showing the same value as it is in a for loop. $j i was trying to check if i am able to do it by setting through the id of the first input field but did not work out.

Answer (score 0):

a) v-model is internally implemented as:

```
<input v-model="myval">
<!-- is --!>
<input :model-value="myval" @update:model-value="v => myval = v">
```

so you can freely define your own function

```
<input v-for="obj, ind of whatever" @update:model-value="v => myfn(v, obj, ind)">
```

---

b) same as you have an array you v-for on you may make a parallel array

```
// you get the idea
data: () => ({ imputs: entries.map(e => 0) })

<div v-for="entry, ind of imputs">
  <Whatever :entry="entry"/>
  <imput v-model="imputs[ind]"> 
</div>
```

---

c) keep your imputs in objects, generally the best choice

```
// you get the idea
data: () => ({ imputs: entries.map(e => ({ entry: e, input: 0 })) })
// or
computed: {pairs(){ return this.entries.map(e => ({ entry: e, input: 0 })) }}

<div v-for="item of imputs">
  <Whatever :entry="item.entry"/>
  <imput v-model="item.input"> 
</div>
```

Comment: Tried the 3rd solution and worked for me . Thanks!! Will post the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can achieve that.

```js
  data() {
    return {
      itemList: [
        { id: 1 , value: '' },
        { id: 2, value: '' },
        { id: 3, value: '' }
      ]
    }
  },
    
  methods:{
    selectingFav: function(value) {
      // value holds the index
      if (value === 1 )
        this.itemList[0].value = this.selected;
      else if(value === 2 )
        this.itemList[1].value = this.selected;
      else
        this.itemList[2].value = this.selected;
      }
    }
  }
```

In HTML template section

```html
<tr v-for="(items,i) in itemList">
  <td valign="top">&nbsp;{{items.id}}&nbsp;</td>
  <td align="left" nowrap>
  <input v-model="items.value" type="text" :id="'item_code_'+items" 
 @input="handleInput" size="20" maxlength="27" autocomplete="off">
  <br/>
</td>
```